# swift/parse: incrementing strings

Tags: string, swift, parse-platform

***The Swift part of the question:***

So what I mean by incrementing strings is that say we start off with `var string = "title"` I want to be able to increment numbers to the end of that like `"title1", "title2", "title3..."`. Should I use a for loop to do this? If so, how? Or another method?

```
for var i = 1; i < 6; i = i + 1 {
        //increment the strings here
    }
```

***The Parse part of the question:***

I want to have my `objectForKey` use the many different titles and numbers we will produce above so that the `objectForKey` will be `"title1", "title2", "title3"...` I would make multiple columns on Parse with names " title1, title2, title3 and the cells in the tableview would correspond to that data. So cell1 would use title1's data, cell2 will use title2's data and so on. Will it work like this?

```
var output1 = object.objectForKey(i) as! String
```

Comment: try something and add to the question.

Comment: `for var i = 0 ; i < 6; i++{ let stringT = "title\(i+1)"  print(stringT)}` you could try something like that to get the title name :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop in Swift is like [`for i in 1...5`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html), and then you can use [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285) to get the correct string like this:

```
for i in 1...5 {
    let title = "title\(i)"
    print(title)
}
```

---

Also read [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552474/11492).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of looping in Swift, but you should keep in mind that and as of **Swift 3**,

**this will no longer be one of them**:

```
for var i = 0; i <6; i++ {
    let string = "title\(i+1)"
}
```

source : [Swift Evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md)

Swift's preferred way of general looping is, as GvS stated:

```
for i in 1...5 {
    let title = "title\(i)"
}
```

However, you are also welcome to use Swifts higher order functions to loop:

```
   (1...5).forEach { i in
        let title = "title \(i)"
    }
```

or

```
(1...5).forEach { let title = "title \($0)" }
```

Comment: Wondering why a "higher order function" is a better solution? Also why `$0` is more clear than `i`?

Comment: @zaph Well, I didn't actually say it was "better" and the opposite could be argued for sure. However, I did want to offer up another reasonable option. One minor benefit to higher order functions is that they allow us to write more terse code. Lastly, I don't think I implied that $0 is more clear than i... It's merely a way to write this loop in a more terse manor.

Comment: Is "more terse code" a good thing? It is more understandable to the next developers or does it cause them to take a moment to understand what is happening? We are after all writing code for the next developer.

Comment: @zaph If your code can be terse and readable then yes its a good thing, no question about it. Theres nothing challenging to reading the first forEach block I provided and I never stated that someone "should" use either of the two, I simply provided them as options. I was rather clear when I stated in my answer that "Swift's **preferred way** of general looping is" the for-in loop. Furthermore, I'm certainly not the person to argue with if you're not a fan of higher order functions, Chris Lattner and the Swift team seem pretty open discussion regarding what they put in the Swift library.

Comment: I have no problem with "higher order functions" when they provide a clearly better implementation. To many times they are used to be "clever". As for Chris, he seems to miss the point that we should write programs to be clear to the next human developer, not either the compiler or to reduce typing, we have IDEs to help with the latter. Sure, the variable name `i` is a throwback to Fortran but I see `$0` as no better. Easier typing is seen in "C" and early unix: `creat()` (where is the 'e') but then we were typing on teletypes.

Comment: For an idea of where I am coming from see [Why Swift guard Should Be Avoided](https://medium.com/swift-programming/why-swift-guard-should-be-avoided-484cfc2603c5#.5ckb0hbor). Edsger Dijkstra:
"The competent programmer is fully aware of the strictly limited size of his own skull; therefore he approaches the programming task in full humility, and among other things he avoids clever tricks like the plague."

Comment: @zaph I'll read through this later tonight when I get a chance. To be clear, I understand your concerns with people overusing higher order functions  however I don't see the harm in telling someone of their existence. The main take-away from my answer was that the askers use of the C style for loop is soon to be deprecated.